# Designing models when data are only temporary

Tags: django, django-models

I am an intermediate programmer, but a beginner in `Django` (and web programming).

I'm trying to learn it by doing a personal project which is a web service to help my church friends find lyrics for multiple songs more easily.

I could easily think of its `view`.

It will have a page with a set of text input fields, that takes the song title and the artist name. The user can add multiple songs by clicking `+` button.

Once that is done and the user clicks `search` button, (after my Python script googles them, finds corresponding lyrics webpage from one of the 'trusted' lyrics websites, and parses the lyrics string), the browser shows a next page that contains text areas, with the lyrics for each song on a text area.

This way they could find lyrics more easily.

Unfortunately, I am having difficulty in designing its `models`.

For now, I am not storing any song titles or lyrics, I just take song titles as inputs and show lyrics as outputs and they are gone.

Thus, I don't think any `model` is necessary for my project. Is it correct?

Or should something else than song titles or lyrics texts be defined as models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly fine without any models, e.g. there are apps that relay the job to another service, or just perform some calculation/processing

On the other hand if you feel it's convenient to store the temporary data as a Django models I don't see why not, it can be practical to cache it so you don't have to run the Python spider for an exact query only 1 minute later

App-specific models would only be required if your app needs to store the data (e.g. a website that lets users create songs/lyrics for later view/search)

Comment: So, one `app` in the project, with model `class Song` that has `title` and `lyrics` and some other fields as its members, correct? You mentioned caching the results this way using a model, but does `filter()` for models provide constant-time lookup?

Comment: Cache as in store in the DB and removed later so you don't keep outdated searches e.g. You can store a `Search(user, timestamp, query)` model and then link `Song` and `Lyrics` to it, then after a period you deem it's not longer useful to keep them, you just cascade delete the `Search`

Comment: With an index it is a constant lookup yeah, I didn't mean cache in memory, although there are plenty of cache systems that work with Django, like memcachd, maybe for your next project!

Comment: Thank you. Could you take a look at my `models.py` code at http://ideone.com/7sC8Uo ?

Comment: Looks good, try this for `DateTimeField` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add